# PHP object-oriented num_rows is 0

Tags: php, mysqli

my problem is that in the if query
`if ($ zugang-> num_row == 1)` `num_rows` is 0

```
$zugang = $db->prepare("SELECT nutzer FROM benutzer WHERE nutzer = ?");
    $zugang->bind_param("s", $nutzerid);
    $zugang->execute();
    $zugang->bind_result($nutzer);
    while ($zugang->fetch()) {

    }

    echo "zugang";
    var_dump($zugang->num_rows);
    print_r($zugang->num_rows);
    if ($zugang->num_rows == 1) {
      $_SESSION['nutzer] = $nutzer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the issue http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-result.num-rows.php#105289

Comment: You have a syntax issue in `$_SESSION['nutzer] = $nutzer;`

Comment: Can you show us the var_dump?

Comment: Use a `$zugang->store_result();` after the execute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be useful:

```
$result = $zugang->get_result();
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
  // some code
}
```